# How can I use my usb hdd as a live installer without formatting it all?

Tags: usb-drive, live-usb, usb-creator

I have some unpartioned space on my usb HDD and I would like to use that space to setup a live ubuntu installation partition. I have a lot of data in other partitions that I want to keep, so I cannot just plug in the usb creator because it seems to want to format the whole thing...

What can I do?

Comment: what utility are you using to install ubuntu live?

Comment: usb-creator-gtk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the Disk Utility or [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) to format the unpartioned space then use [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) to install live ubuntu to that partition.  Make sure you select the right one!

Comment: That worked, but somehow unetbootin screwed the partition on which I was running Ubuntu. Not that much of a problem since I was trying to reinstall on that computer, but that experience didn't really make me want to use unetbootin.

Answer (score 0):

use Gparted or the integrated utility Palimpsest which comes with the latests versions of Ubuntu http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palimpsest_Disk_Utility